# how can i pass id of object vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

how can i pass id of object vue js

I have a json file, from it I need to get the id of the selected option from the selector

```
<div class="select">
  <div class="select-header form-control" v-on:click="AddForm(1)">
    <span class="select__current" v-if="status_id == null">Please select status</span>
    <span v-else>{{ typeStatus[status_id].name }}</span>
  </div>
  <div class=" select__body" v-if="addedForm === 1">
    <div class="select-item" v-for="(type, index) in typeStatus" v-bind:key="type.id" v-on:click="status_id = index; addedForm = false;">
      {{ type.name }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

methods: {
    search() {
        this.filter.append('status', this.typeStatus[this.status_id].id)
        this.$emit('filter', this.filter);
    },
}
```

Comment: I need an id to bind the selection, not to display

Comment: I need to send the status_id of the selected option in the filter request

https://prnt.sc/v1d0zr

Comment: I did, but thanks anyway